# VSCode: cannot remote debug python script on Docker container because the connection fails

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, docker-container

I read many similar questions but I couldn't find any answer for me. I also went through the documentation: [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-common#_python).

I'm running an Ubuntu container on Windows and I read about the [limitation in Networking](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#there-is-no-docker0-bridge-on-windows#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host).

I ran the container with -p 3000:3000

The error => connect ETIMEDOUT

This is my launch.json

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 3000,
        "host": "172.17.0.2",
        "pathMappings": [
            {
              "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/somefolder/somefolder",
              "remoteRoot": "/rootfolder/"
            }
          ]
    },
```

This is my tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "docker-build",
            "label": "docker-build",
            "platform": "python",
            "dockerBuild": {
                "tag": "test:latest",
                "dockerfile": "${workspaceFolder}/somefolder/somefolder",
                "context": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "pull": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "docker-run",
            "label": "docker-run: debug",
            "dependsOn": ["docker-build"],
            "python": {
                "module": "C:\\...\\somefolder"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [remote extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) for VS Code?

Comment: Hi, thanks I adopted your solution and it's working. If you wish you can post an answer with the links.

Comment: I've gotten in trouble previously for posting answers that were basically just links, but we will give it a go and see if anyone objects.

Comment: Since nobody provided an answer that is the direct fix of my issue I'll temporarily accept yours as an alternative and valid solution to my problem. If someone object I can remove the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [remote extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) as it should handle all of this transparently.

[This](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) is the extension for Visual Studio Code to remote debug in containers. You can attach a python script to a running container and it will import all the needed dependencies.